# Nested cross validation with caret

Tags: r, nested, cross-validation, r-caret, resampling

I have worked with a small dataset and have used nested cross validation with the mlr package. However, caret has some advantages to test different models. So, I would like to know: Would anyone have any good suggestions (and an example, if possible) of how to implement nested cross validation using caret?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you find anything usefull in the meantime?

Comment: This looks promising: https://github.com/sebastiansauer/reanalysis-mindful-machine-learning/issues/1#issue-506641549

Comment: `rsample` from **tidymodels** seems designed to help, perhaps can be used in a **caret** workflow https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/work/nested-resampling/